# Can't delete database snapshot SQL Server, Error: 946

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, snapshot

I need to drop a snapshot of a database using SQL Server 2014 (in order to drop the database itself).  When I attempt to drop the database...

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'xxx'
GO

USE [master]
GO

DROP DATABASE [xxx]
GO
```

I get the following error...

> Drop failed for Database 'xxx'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Cannot open database 'xxx' version 706. Upgrade the database to the latest version. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 946)
>
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3S2sioQNnAwSEs1RmN6UDJ2N0U/view?usp=sharing

Could this be a result of a connection that needs to be closed?

Comment: Which version of sql server and ssms? Please post the sql statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem.  I simply needed to execute the below statements.

```
    ALTER DATABASE [Your DB Here] SET OFFLINE
    Drop database [Your DB snapshot here]
```

Comment: Thanks to those who edited (this was my first post).

Answer (score 0):

We just had a similar issue and the accepted answer didn't work. The snapshot was `Suspect` but the database was not. This solution will only work if you no longer need the database attached to the snapshot. We end up having to stop the sql server service rename all database files: `.MDF, .LDF, .SS`. We then, finally, were able to delete the snapshot & database.